# Why does invalid memset() after malloc() leads to free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, memory, free, memcpy, memset

Code snippet, at the bottom, which I was trying lead to the following error

```
free(): invalid next size (fast)
```

Above error, was caused by declaration of integer variable ***mock*** after accidently calling memset() on pointer ***check*** with size more than what was originally allocated using malloc(). And when free() is called on pointer ***check*** it leads to a runtime error.

It would be helpful if somebody could explain how the internal memory is being manipulated or why this error actually occurred.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *check = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    memset(check, 0, 100);

    memcpy(check, "memsetcpy", 10);

    int mock = 9;

    free(check);

    return 1;
}
```

**EDIT** My intention of asking the question was to know/understand what happens to the book-keeping information in the heap memory when the program runs. And may be to have some information on data structures that are modified would be great. 
OR I wanted to know from the design perspective.

Thanks everyone for chipping-in.

Comment: You're writing way past what you allocated.

Comment: @Mysticial:  It is closer than a longshot, but I think this has a distinct flavor for heap overrun rather than stack overrun.  No difference from a computer science perspective, but they are quite different from an implementation and practical perspective.

Comment: @Mysticial: I agree with wallyk.  Both are array overruns, but the possible duplicate is C++ rather than C, and the issue here is dynamically allocated memory whereas the other is not.  I think those keep them 'not exact duplicate' though related.  Also, it is itself closed as a duplicate; it would be better to chase the chain back to the most nearly authoritative Q&A.

Comment: I think it's close to being a duplicate, but this is perhaps the best-formed version of the question I've seen, especially from a new SO user, and thus I'm inclined not to close it.

Comment: @R.. Agreed. Then perhaps we should make *this* question the canonical.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd call that pretty good dupe. Not only is it also caused by overrunning the allocated region, but it also has the error in the title.

Comment: I agree it's close to a duplicate but my intention of asking the question was to know/understand what happens to the book-keeping information in the heap memory when the program runs. May be I should edit my question. thanks everyone.

Comment: @Mysticial: Can you take a quick look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254782/a-long-list-of-possible-duplicates-c-memory-allocation-and-overrunning-bounds; I'm planning to use Mjölnir to duplicate them to the first.

Comment: What happens, Varun, depends on the implementation of `malloc()` et al that you are using.  Different versions map bits of memory differently, and overwriting beyond the bounds therefore has different effects depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical dynamic memory (heap) implementation stores a lot of household information right there, in the very same memory, interleaved with user data. Each block of memory you allocate typically includes a special header region and, possibly, a special footer region. These regions surround your user region from both ends. You are only allowed to manipulate memory inside your user region. But the moment you write anything outside the boundaries of that user region, you most certainly damage those internal header and footer regions. This completely destroys the integrity of dynamic memory management subsystem. The rest follows.

In your case you go outside your user region by 90 bytes. This is a lot. You probably destroyed a lot of internal household data that is critical for proper operation of dynamic memory.

The specific details of this (what gets damaged and how it affects `free` later) are very, very, very implementation-dependent. Different implementations can be wildly different in that regard. There's no way to provide a more specific description without at least knowing what specific implementation you are using.

Comment: This answer covers the mechanism really well, but so far we're missing any good coverage of the formal reason the code breaks - an explanation of what undefined behavior means, how it applies to heap overruns, and the potential motivations for leaving behavior undefined (allowing diverse implementations).

Comment: Close to what I wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When the program writes outside defined memory space, ***anything*** could happen.

In this case, the program has damaged the [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28programming%29#Dynamic_memory_allocation).

Answer (score 3):

This is the signature of `memset`:

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

With `malloc`, you allocate 10 bytes of memory, and assign a pointer to that memory to `check`. (Not a solution, but you [should not cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/))

Then with `memset`, you write 100 bytes of zeroes to the block of memory pointed to by `check`.

Your program writes correctly to the first ten bytes, then zeroes out whatever is in the 90 following the allocated space. Since you're writing outside of allocated memory, anything could happen, and in this case, I'd guess you're writing over memory that contains bookkeeping info for the `malloc`/`free` memory allocation system. Of course, since you're invoking undefined behavior, it would also be acceptable for it to cause your computer to grow legs and walk away.

Comment: +1 from today, I will write a lot of undefined program. If it cause it to grow a leg that would be a huge success. :D

Comment: If you manage it, make sure to let me know - I'd love to co-author a paper on the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

In modern operating systems, allocated memory is managed in very large chunks from kernel space and then allocated in smaller chunks by user space code.

The user space code keeps track of the allocated and free memory typically through the use of a doubly linked list along with sentinel data before and after each allocated chunk. The sentinel data includes things like a magic number, chunk size, etc.

The sentinel data helps the memory manager detect when a user program writes past (or before) it's allocated size. The use of a doubly linked list helps the memory manager combine the freed smaller chunks into larger freed segments to help avoid fragmentation.

When you write beyond your allocated size, you not only destroy the sentinel data but also probably the linked-list data. Once the linked list gets destroyed, most memory managers fall apart thus the comments about things going off the reservation.

Hope this helps.